# Catch cin exception

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

I want to ask the user for input, which I get with cin like this

```
void AskForGroundstate() {
    cout << "Please enter an groundstate potential value in Volt:" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> _VGroundstate)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Groundstate potential not valid." << endl;
        AskForGroundstate();
    }
}
```

_VGroundstate is a double, so if the user enters an String with not numbers, it should ask him again for a better input. But the problem is, that when the input is for example "AA", than the program executes AskForGroundstate two times, with "AAA" three times etc. Did I use the clear wrong?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Vgroundstate`) and names that contain two underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cin.ignore()` drops one character; you want to drop all characters to end of line:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This ensures that all invalid input is dropped before end-users are prompted for input again.

Comment: There Clion says, canot resolve container numeric_limits ?

Comment: @LucaThiede, Like everything else in the standard library, you have to include its header, `<limits>`.

Comment: @LucaThiede You need to include [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) header.